# What is the probability of getting $8-6$ (Win-lose), when you bet $14$ times in a win or lose game with $60$% winning percentage?

Tags: binomial-distribution

What is the probability of getting $8-6$ (Win-lose), when you bet 14 times in a win or lose a game with $60%$ winning percentage?

According to the answer, it must be $ 17.4$%.

I tried to solve this using binomial distribution but my answer is not $ 17.4$%.
Here is my solution:

$B(x;n,p) = B(8;14,0.6)$ = $14 \choose 8$$(0.6)^8(0.4)^6$ $= (3003)(0.6)^8(0.4)^6$ $= 0.20659760529408$

Here is the exact problem

"Let’s say, based on your betting system’s 60% winning percentage, you want to know Harvard's most likely record over the next 14 bets. 60% of 14 is 8.4, so our record should be 8-6. Using the binomial distribution calculator, we learn that even though 8-6 is the most likely record, it will actually only occur 17.4% of the time. Show that it will actually only occur 17.4% of the time."

Please help me solve this problem. Any comments or suggestions will be much appreciated.

Comment: What answer did you get; and how did you get it?

Comment: I get $0.206597605$,  I can't come up with a way to get $.174$

Comment: Can you print the problem exactly as it appears, with no edits?  Or include a link to the source (if possible).  As stated, the $20.7\%$ answer appears to be correct.

Comment: @lulu I include here the actual text of the problem. Thank you!

Comment: Well, it's confusing.  The problem says "your betting system" has a $60\%$ winning percentage...but then the rest of the problem doesn't mention "your betting system".  It all concerns "Harvard's record"  which, for some reason, also appears to have a $60\%$ winning percentage.  Also, both $(8,6)$ and $(9,5)$ are equally probable though for some reason they fix on $(8,6)$.  But I still can't guess where the $17.4\%$ comes from.

Comment: In Bin(x;n,p) with x = 8 and n = 14 17.4% arises when one takes e.g. p = 0.488 or p = 0.652, but that does not explain how they get it here, since they state p = 0.6..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As you probabily already did, the probability to get 8 successes on 14 independent draws is

$$\binom{14}{8}0.6^8 0.4^6\approx 20.7\%$$

Edit: reading the text, the probability that there is an error (more than one error) is getting higher and higher.

Here is the graph of your 60% winning game (with 14 independent trials)

[image]

As you can see, the most likely events are 2, with same 20.7% probability